# Escape brackets in titles of questions when voting to close as a duplicate

Tags: bug, user-interface, exact-duplicates, markdown, hyperlinks

When you vote to close a question as a duplicate, the software automatically puts a comment looking like `Possible duplicate of [Duplicate title](Duplicate link).`. When "Duplicate title" contains a bracket `]`, it breaks the markdown and the link doesn't work. This probably doesn't happen often on other sites, but MSE titles contain brackets often enough. Could it be possible to escape these brackets so as to not break the markdown?

Comment: I realize it's a minor issue, but it would be nice to have it fixed.

Comment: This was pointed out before.

Comment: [Indeed, I hadn't found it for some reason...](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11662/markdown-quirk-including-square-brackets-in-link-text-of-comment) It doesn't look like the devs cared though (or saw the post). Oh well.

Comment: If you are aware of the issue when voting, then you can manually edit the Comment (since it appears "as if" it were posted by you, even though automatically generated).  Some judgement is probably called for in applying the escapes or removing the original MarkDown characters.